# Trying to rotate an AVL Tree, height issue

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree

I'm trying to implement an AVL Tree, but I can't even pass an if statement

```
void AVL::insert(Node **r,Node data){  // insert(&root,data)
    if(!(*r)){
       (*r)= new Node();
       (**r) = data;
       if( abs( height((*r)->left) - height((*r)->right) ) > 1 ){...}
       ...
       ...
    }
    else
        if(data.value<(*r)->value)
           insert(&((*r)->left),data);
        else
           insert(&((*r)->right),data);
}
```

My height Function:

```
int AVL::height(Node *p){
   if (!p) return 0;
   int left = height(p->left);
   int right = height(p->right);
   return (1 + max(left,right));
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, everything should work fine. I tried to output "test" before the if statement = if(abs( height((*r)->left) - height((*r)->right) ) >1 ) and works perfect, tried inside the statement and never go in.

My actual tree:

```
      100
    90
  80
70
```

Should Be something like this:

```
    90
  80  100
70
```

If you need more info, just let me know.

Comment: Single-step through `insert` with your debugger and see where it goes off the rails.

Comment: Already did that, that's why I made this post. The insert Function works fine, the only thing that isn't working is the height() function. Height() function should tell me when the tree is unbalanced, and if returns a value > 1, my code can do the respective job.

Comment: height() looks good to me. I don't see any rotation code of the tree though after you have inserted a node. If the rotation code is in the `{...}` part (after comparing abs of left-right heights), then it wont work since you only rotate the sub-tree, not the entire tree. You didn't post enough code to give proper answer though, but I assume you don't hold parent node pointer and traverse the tree up in that rotation code, but rotate only the sub-tree at the current root.

Comment: Ok I'll post the whole code in a few. I understand your point. Makes sense to me.